# R remove duplicates completely across different groups

Tags: r, unique, data-cleaning

I have a dataset like the following:

[image]

R code to replicate the dataset:

```
mydata <- data.frame(Name =c('Alex','Brenda','Carl','Alex','Daniel',
'Einstein','Frodo','Alex','Brenda','Carl','Einstein','Frodo'),
 Product_Name = c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'), 
Use = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1))
mydata
```

This is a dataset from a survey of product usage. Name contains name of the user, Product_Name is the name of the product (Product A or Product B. In the real dataset, there are more than 2) and Use contains information whether the user uses the product (1 = yes, 0 = no).

Unfortunately some individuals selected both yes and no to questions regarding whether they use a product or not. I want to remove these individuals but only for the Product_Name in question. In the example, user Alex replied yes and no for product A:

[image]

I want to remove such individuals but I want to remove them only for the product concerned. Here I only want to remove Alex for Product A and leave Alex for Product B. This should be how I want the dataset to look like:

[image]

I know that I can remove duplicates using the unique package in R (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html) but that would still leave one case of Alex in Product 1. I would also like to limit the search for unique names within each Product_Name (ie. only Product A or Product B and so on). Any help will be appreciated.

Please let me know if the question is not very clear. Thanks in advance.

**FOLLOW UP QUESTION**

Now suppose we have the following scenario:

```
mydata <- data.frame(Name =c('Alex','Brenda','Carl','Alex','Daniel',
'Einstein','Frodo','Alex','Brenda','Carl','Einstein','Frodo',
'Mary','Mary','Richard','Richard'),
 Product_Name = c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B',
 'B','C','C','C','C'), 
Use = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1))
```

In addition to the above condition where if a person has use =0 and use = 1 then they are deleted I have an additional condition. If Use = 0 and we see multiple entries for same user, then we do not delete the observations. However,if Use = 1 and we see multiple instances of the same user then we delete them. For instance, in the figure below, I would like to keep the observations for Mary and drop the observations for Richard.

[image]

The final output that I would like to get would look something like this:

[image]

In this figure, note that I do not want to delete Mary since for both instances Use =0. However since Use = 1 for Richard, I would like to delete his observations.

[image]

Comment: You should looking into grouping by a variable. For example with dplyr you can do: `group_by(mydata, Name, Product_Name) %>% filter(n() == 1)`

Comment: `mydata[with(mydata, ave(Use, Name, Product_Name)) %in% 0:1, ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Original Question

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
        group_by(Product_Name, Name) %>%
        filter(length(Use) == 1)
```

#### Follow-up Question

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
        group_by(Product_Name, Name) %>%
        filter(length(Use) == 1 | (Use == 0 & n_distinct(Use) == 1))
```

Comment: I had a follow up question. Suppose I wanted to add one more condition to this. Suppose for Product_Name - B , we have two entries for Alex under use = 0. In that case I would like to keep both cases. However, if we observe Use = 1 twice or more then I would like to delete it. Would you know what I would need to do in that case? I will edit my orginal question with the follow so that it is easier to see what I mean. Thanks a lot again @blondeclover

Comment: Worked like a charm. You are awesome. @blondeclover

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rely on base R, you could use `aggregate` to count the number of times occurrences of each `(Name - Product_Name)`-combination. Then create a blacklist to remove all `(Name - Product_Name)`-combinations on that blacklist from `mydata`:

```
inter     <- aggregate(df, by=list(df$Name, df$Product_Name), FUN="length")
blacklist <- inter[c('Group.1', 'Group.2')][inter$Name > 1, ]
for(i in nrow(blacklist)){
  r  <- blacklist[i, ]
  df <- df[!(df$Name == r[[1]] & df$Product_Name == r[[2]]), ]
}
```

I must admit that the `dplyr` answers are about 10 times nicer